# Image analysis on the iPhone

Tags: image, image-processing

Hopefully a quick one. Working on a devious little algorithm that'll automatically scan a user's iPhone for a photo of some emotional poignance (e.g. go back in time a ways, look for one of a group of photos that are proximally timestamped, etc.). Need a quick-and-dirty way of picking out a photo containing two people in close proximity to each other. I know that the OpenCV Python lib [for image processing] works on the iPhone, I'm just curious whether it's actually the best way of doing this (from scratch or otherwise).

Cheers!